# Issue while using map_partitions in dask with a power function on pandas table with list elements

Tags: python, dask

I am having the following code in python developed using the Dask framework:

```
# Create a Pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': [[1], [2], [3], [4], [5]],
    'B': [[6], [7], [8], [9], [10]]
})

# Convert the Pandas DataFrame to a Dask DataFrame
ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=2)

def my_function2(x):
    return x[0]**2

# Define a function to apply to each partition
def my_function(df):
    return df.map(my_function2)

# Apply the function to each partition of the Dask DataFrame
result = ddf.map_partitions(my_function).compute()
```

When I execute it get the following error: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'str' and 'int'`

This is a short version of my code. It essentially applies a power operator on floating numbers in the pandas table which is stored as a list in each cell of the table. What could be the reason for this error? I tried `np.power(x[0])` and `x[0]*x[0]` instead of `x[0]**2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is happening during dask trying to guess what the outcome types of map_partitions will be. It uses dummy values for the columns rather than a potentially large dataframe, and your lists give the columns "list" type. Since the most common values in an "object" type column are strings, you get to the error you see.

The solution is to tell map_partitions what you expect.

```
result = ddf.map_partitions(my_function, meta=pd.DataFrame({"A": [0], "B": [0]})).compute()
```